# url for Active Storage in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, rails-activestorage

2 and Active Storage (Nginx + Passenger).
I sometimes have problems with rendering images I got the incorrect url.

Sometimes I have the source url `https://example.org/rails/active_storage/blobs/..` and sometimes  `https://example.org/rails/active_storage/disc/..`

`image_tag url_for(event.logo)`
If I reload the page I have got normal img - with the correct url.
I didn't find information on how they generated url, and why they have got different url

Change used method for url

1. image_tag event.logo - clear method without url_for
2. Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(event.logo, only_path: true)

Comment: Have you read the ActiveStorage guide (https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html)? Are the problem images ones that you've just uploaded, or already stored? Your question needs more context.

Comment: Of course, what should I write? 
I think it's a problem with the cache, the cache in my browser doesn't update in time.
I know for sure that problem with the image appears in next day